# JavaFX code optimization for MVC-pattern rules

Tags: java, oop, javafx, optimization, model-view-controller

I have a code that implements logic of simple java app for unit-convertations. I think I can optimize it for MVC-model and simplify my code by splitting main class into subclasses. I tried to do this by myself but I got some troubles with static/non-static methods combinations. What is the better way to solve this?

Here is my code example:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    public Button convertButtonLength;
    public Button convertMassButton;

    public TextField lengthInputField;
    public TextField massInputField;

    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> lengthFromCB;
    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> lengthToCB;
    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> massFromCB;
    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> massToCB;
 
    private void showResult(String conversation) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Result window");
        alert.setHeaderText("Results: ");
        alert.setContentText(conversation);

        alert.showAndWait();
    }


    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        lengthFromCB.setItems(lengthValues);
        lengthToCB.setItems(lengthValues);
        convertButtonLength.setOnAction(event -> showResult(lengthConvert()));

        massFromCB.setItems(massValues);
        massToCB.setItems(massValues);
        convertMassButton.setOnAction(event -> showResult(massConvert()));

        
    }

    static ObservableList<String> lengthValues = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            null,
            "Metres",
            "Kilometres",
            "Miles"

    );


    private String lengthConvert() {

        double result = 0;
        String valueCB1 = lengthFromCB.getValue();
        String valueCB2 = lengthToCB.getValue();

        try {
            var inputData = Double.parseDouble(lengthInputField.getText().trim().replace(",", "."));
            if (inputData < 0) {
                throw new UnexpectedException(Constants.NE_WARN);
            }

            if (valueCB1.equals(lengthValues.get(0)) ^ valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(0))) {
                return "No Item is Selected";
            }
            if (valueCB1.equals(lengthValues.get(1))) {
                if (valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(1))) result = inputData;
                if (valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(2))) result = inputData * 0.001;
                if (valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(3))) result = inputData / 1609.34;
            }

            if (valueCB1.equals(lengthValues.get(2))) {
                if (valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(2))) result = inputData;
                if (valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(1))) result = inputData * 1000;
                if (valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(3))) result = inputData / 1.609;
            }

            if (valueCB1.equals(lengthValues.get(3))) {
                if (valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(3))) result = inputData;
                if (valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(1))) result = inputData * 1609;
                if (valueCB2.equals(lengthValues.get(2))) result = inputData * 1.609;
            }
            return inputData + " " + valueCB1 + " = " + result + " " + valueCB2;

        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            return Constants.NPE_WARN;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return Constants.NFE_WARN;
        } catch (UnexpectedException ne) {
            return Constants.NE_WARN;
        }


    }

    static ObservableList<String> massValues = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Grams",
            "Kilograms",
            "Pounds",
            "Ounces"

    );

    private String massConvert() {
        double result = 0;
        String valueCB1 = massFromCB.getValue();
        String valueCB2 = massToCB.getValue();
        try {
            var inputData = Double.parseDouble(massInputField.getText().trim().replace(",", "."));
            if (inputData < 0) {
                throw new UnexpectedException(Constants.NE_WARN);
            }
            if (valueCB1.equals(massValues.get(0))) {
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(0))) result = inputData;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(1))) result = inputData * 0.001;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(2))) result = inputData * 0.0022;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(3))) result = inputData * 0.035;
            }
            if (valueCB1.equals(massValues.get(1))) {
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(0))) result = inputData * 1000;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(1))) result = inputData;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(2))) result = inputData * 2.2;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(3))) result = inputData * 35.2;
            }
            if (valueCB1.equals(massValues.get(2))) {
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(0))) result = inputData * 454;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(1))) result = inputData / 2.2;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(2))) result = inputData;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(3))) result = inputData * 16;
            }
            if (valueCB1.equals(massValues.get(3))) {
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(0))) result = inputData * 28.35;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(1))) result = inputData / 35.28;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(2))) result = inputData / 16;
                if (valueCB2.equals(massValues.get(3))) result = inputData;
            }


            return inputData + " " + valueCB1 + " = " + result + " " + valueCB2;

        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            return Constants.NPE_WARN;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return Constants.NFE_WARN;
        } catch (UnexpectedException ne) {
            return Constants.NE_WARN;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is supposed to be an MVC design, where is your model?

Comment: *Never* catch NullPointerException.  That exception means the programmer made a mistake, and that mistake needs to be fixed, not hidden.  Your other `catch` blocks need to show the entire stack trace of the caught exception, either with [printStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) or by logging it.  It’s very difficult to address problems without knowing where and why they happened!